# Get user with highest and lowest value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite and trying to get the users with the lowest and the highest summed up score from all their comments - *that is to get users with the lowest and highest combined score*. The table with the scores to sum up looks kinda like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
     id PRIMARY KEY,
     username STRING,
     body TEXT,
     score INT
);
```

I'm expecting a result like this, displaying the users with the highest and lowest combined score:

```
userMin|-194
userMax|543
```

I'm able to display either the user with the lowest score, or the user with the highest score alone, but can't get them to display simultaneously. This how I get the MAX and MIN:

```
SELECT username,  
   MAX(combinedSum) 
FROM (SELECT author, SUM(score) AS combinedSum FROM comments GROUP BY username) 
   comments;

=> userMax|543
```

or

```
SELECT username,  
   MIN(combinedSum) 
FROM (SELECT author, SUM(score) AS combinedSum FROM comments GROUP BY username) 
   comments;

=> userMin|-194
```

Could somebody please help me how to do this?

Comment: You can use `union` to combine those 2 queries

Comment: @juergend Yeah, it worked! Don't know if there's a more convenient query to not do duplicates, but if not I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this query:**

```
 SELECT username,  
       MAX(combinedSum) 
    FROM (SELECT author, SUM(score) AS combinedSum FROM comments GROUP BY username) 
       comments;
    UNION
    SELECT username,  
       MIN(combinedSum) 
    FROM (SELECT author, SUM(score) AS combinedSum FROM comments GROUP BY username) 
       comments;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select username, sum(score) as sum_score
      from comments
      group by username
     )
select t.*
from t join
     (select min(sum_score) as min_sum_score, max(sum_score) as max_sum_score
      from t
     ) tt
     on t.sum_score in (tt.min_sum_score, tt.max_sum_score);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (SELECT a, sum(b) 'b' from t group by a) tt1 
where b in(select max(t1.b) from(SELECT a, sum(b) 'b' from t group by a) t1
    union select min(t2.b) from(SELECT a, sum(b) 'b' from t group by a) t2)
```

It seems like HAVING can't do the work after all

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: +1 for group by/having. Too many answers about sql try to build something convoluted when those builtins can do the work.

Comment: `max(score)` computes the largest individual score in each group.

Comment: This is not supported by SQLite.